# Drawing lines on Maps (eg. Neighbourhoods or Streets) and then importing into SQL Server?

Tags: software-recommendations, map-drawing

I wish to draw some custom boundaries (eg. neighbourhoods or streets or city boundaries).

1. What software (free or paid) can I use to do this? I read that google maps recently has support for this?
2. Import this boundary into Sql Server 2008.

Are there any links, tutorials or info anyone can provide, please?

Comment: How long do you want to do it for Mike?  Could download an eval if its for one job.  Other than that, if you just want to do something lite, then get onto ebay and buy an old copy of MapInfo 6, as that will do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

1. [Digitize](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmQOa8vi4Ws) the features in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (which is free software)
2. Use [SQL Server 2008 Spatial Tools](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx) (free), [Shape2SQL](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL.aspx) in particular, to import your resulting shapefile(s) you created in QGIS into SQL Server

Some Googling or searching on this site will get you links to other QGIS tutorials on digitizing and just using QGIS in general.

Comment: You may also have success connecting directly to SQL Server from within QGIS - see http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/opening-ms-sql-spatial-in-qgis/ (never done it myself, so can't speak to stability &c). Probably creating a Shapefile and importing is easiest in this situation.

Comment: @mattwigway just a note: there is native support for SQL Server coming for QGIS in the near future. Development is in the works.

Comment: also this http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/opening-ms-sql-server-2008-spatial-tables-in-qgis-correctly/ is the better post for the MS SQL stuff

Comment: @NathanW excellent! It seems like a lot of people are moving towards SQL Server from Oracle.